# mySite is working on :8080 not in www.mysite.com, Using Apache Tomcat in Linux

Tags: java, linux, oracle, apache, tomcat7

I moved to a new server and I installed Oracle Linux operating system, and Oracle database on the machine.

Then according this [tutorial](https://oracle-base.com/articles/linux/apache-tomcat-7-installation-on-linux) I installed Apache - 7 and JDK 1.8

But when I attempt to access it as ww.mysite.com it does not work.

But when I attempt to access with ww.mysite.com:8080 I can access the site.

How can I change my site to work on ww.mysite.com

My `server.xml` file below:

```
<Connector
    port="8080"
    protocol="HTTP/1.1"
    connectionTimeout="20000"
    redirectPort="8443" 
    compression="on" 
    noCompressionUserAgents="gozilla, traviata"
    compressableMimeType="text/html,text/xml,text/css,image/svg+xml,image/gif,image/jpeg,image/png,text/plain,application/xhtml+xml,application/javascript,application/json,text/javascript"
    maxThreads="350"
    threadPriority="java.lang.Thread.MAX_PRIORITY"
    acceptCount="200"
/>
```

Comment: Have you tried changing `<Connector port="8080"` to `<Connector port="80"` ?

Comment: http default port is `80`, change port "8080" to "80"

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with Oracle linux, but from experience with other flavours is port 80 allowing incoming traffic to the server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying a lot of things. i found solution.

with command line on linux terminal i installed httpd

```
sudo yum install httpd
```

then i change my port number from 80 to 8080 in server.xml

```
<Connector
    port="8080"
    protocol="HTTP/1.1"
    connectionTimeout="20000"
    redirectPort="8443" 
    compression="on" 
    noCompressionUserAgents="gozilla, traviata"
    compressableMimeType="text/html,text/xml,text/css,image/svg+xml,image/gif,image/jpeg,image/png,text/plain,application/xhtml+xml,application/javascript,application/json,text/javascript"
    maxThreads="350"
    threadPriority="java.lang.Thread.MAX_PRIORITY"
    acceptCount="200"
/>
```

In linux command line i change my user to tomcat user. which was create as the link below for apache tomcat purpose.
https://oracle-base.com/articles/linux/apache-tomcat-7-installation-on-linux

Run apache tomcat - >

./startup.sh

change user to main one and open the httpd.conf file.

```
/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
```

edit file with vi linux command

```
vi httpd.conf
```

Add this one

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName ww.mysite.com
    ProxyRequests Off
    <Proxy *>
      Order deny,allow
      Allow from all
    </Proxy>
    ProxyPass /     http://ww.mysite.com:8080/
    ProxyPassReverse /  http://ww.mysite.com:8080/
    ErrorLog logs/mysite.com-error_log
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to change port="8080" to port="80", because 80 ist the http standard port. When not on the standard port, you need to add the port the the calling URL. - The same is for https where standard Port is 443.
Btw. don't forget to restart Tomcat after changing the server.xml ;-)

-- edit

Also you should take care about your firewall on the system you are working as well as maybe on your router. You need to open port 80 there for incoming requests. But you should make sure that nobody could hack your system/network.

For this most people use an Apache HTTPD in front of a tomcat for exaple to filter SQL injections etc.

-- edit

For the case that tomcat would not start, you might also have to check if some other thing on your system is already listening on port 80.

-- edit

Last but not least ports <= 1024 are privileged, so you need to run tomcat with these privileges.

Comment: I did the same thing but again same problem.

Answer (score 1):

Change the port to 80 in the first line as below:

```
<Connector port="80" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
 connectionTimeout="20000"
 redirectPort="8443" 
compression="on" 
              noCompressionUserAgents="gozilla, traviata"
              compressableMimeType="text/html,text/xml,text/css,image/svg+xml,image/gif,image/jpeg,image/png,text/plain,application/xhtml+xml,application/javascript,application/json,text/javascript"
              maxThreads="350"
              threadPriority="java.lang.Thread.MAX_PRIORITY"
              acceptCount="200"
            />
```

Iyi calismalar,

Comment: I change it but , same problem again. tesekkur ederim.